# How do I make all but a certain colour black in an image?

Tags: c#, image

I have an image with a lot of green in it, but also a large amount of different coloured pixels. The green is not an issue. How can I turn all non-green pixels black?

Comment: How are you defining 'green'...

Comment: green as in `#00FF00` or shades of green?

Comment: As the Color.Green value

Comment: What format is the image in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In p-code:

```
for each pixel
    if pixel is not green
        pixel <- black
```